# PIC18F26K83 Can Bus Mode 0(legacy mode) supports extended ID's?

Tags: c, pic

I am trying to send/receive data with J1939 protocol. So in PIC18F26K83 there are 3 modes for can bus Mode 0: Legacy, Mode 1: Enhanced Legacy and Mode 2: FIFO. I want to use 29 bit extended identifier messages but I am not sure if i can use Mode 0 for this operation. In datasheet it is not really clear and in some lines it says something like extended identifiers are not supported in Mode 0. To sum up can I use extended ID's in Mode 0( legacy mode) for PIC18F26K83? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not see why you can't use 29 bits identifiers in Mode 0. Literally, I can't see in the datasheet where it says anything about it.

Besides, what it does say is that Mode 0 is made to be fully compatible with PICs like 18Fxx8, which are actually compatible with 29 bits identifiers.

Comment: Yes you are right so do you know what are the purpose of  WIN bits in CANCON register?  It says  "This allows access to the buffer registers from any data memory bank."

Comment: I am no expert setting up CAN in this uC but I believe WIN is nothing essential. Take a look at this, maybe it helps understand at least if you can avoid messing with that. https://www.microchip.com/forums/m131488.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, WIN is not essential its for mapping registers.